# How to influence NLTK to tag city as GPE instead of Verb

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am looking for a way to influence the behavior of the IoB tagging of pythons NLTK.
Consider the following piece of code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer 
from nltk.tag import untag, str2tuple, tuple2str
from nltk.chunk import tree2conllstr, conllstr2tree, conlltags2tree, tree2conlltags
import nltk

text = "Drive me from Seattle to Brussels"
# Morphology - tagging the words
tokens = word_tokenize(text)

# Part of speech tagging
tagged_tokens = pos_tag(tokens)

# Create named entity tree of tagged tokens
ner_tree = ne_chunk(tagged_tokens)

# Get tag structure
iob_tagged = tree2conlltags(ner_tree)
print(iob_tagged)
```

This outputs the following values:

[('Drive', 'VB', 'O'), ('me', 'PRP', 'O'), ('from', 'IN', 'O'), ('Seattle', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('Brussels', 'VB', 'O')]

Is there a way I can influence or tune the NLTK algorithm/model in a way that the last word (Brussels) is tagged as a Geopolitical Entity (GPE), instead of a verb?  I understand the verb is there, because it is following the To word, which is often used prior to verbs.

Comment: Have you tried "SpaCy"? I think it is better in this.

Comment: Thanks @Peyman - I will look into it.  However, the excercise is for my study and the task at hand requires us to use NLTK.

Comment: Taggers work with Hidden Markov chains training bi-grams or tri-grams. This failure of correctly distinguishing a verb-like token from a city as a locative is not your fault, but dependent on the training data used for the NLTK toolkit. If your task is to use nltk, then your supervisors have to accept this, since it is simply not your fault. Instead, you could use nltk to train your own Markov Model, then you used the NLTK but you may get better results. Also, you could write some kind of a post-processor that corrects your incorrect GPE classification. This is probably the better idea.